# ERROR TypeError: TaskQueue: Error with task : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'inputCard.current.value.replace')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling

## code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const PhoneSetting = () => {
  const [card, setCard] = useState();
  const inputCard = useRef(); //'+1 650-555-3434'

  const handleChange = () => {
    const cardValue = inputCard.current.value
      .replace(/\D/g, '')
      .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/);
    inputCard.current.value = !cardValue[2]
      ? cardValue[1]
      : `${cardValue[1]}-${cardValue[2]}${`${cardValue[3] ? `-${cardValue[3]}` : ''
      }`}${`${cardValue[4] ? `-${cardValue[4]}` : ''}`}`;
    const numbers = '+91' + inputCard.current.value.replace(/(\D)/g, '');
    setCard(numbers);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange();
  }, [card]);

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        ref={inputCard}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter number"
      />
      <TextInput value={card} />
    </>
  );
};

export default PhoneSetting;
```

it's properly work on [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@gattu/disabled-input-in-react-native-paper) but when I try to run on my react native project it's give me error where is problem and why it's run properly on snack

## error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: TaskQueue: Error with task : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'inputCard.current.value.replace')
```

Comment: That's because the snack is using javascript and you use typescript, so you have to do non-null/undefined check before going further in ìnputCard` structure

Comment: how can soul this issue?